# Adding sublayers while animating parent CALayer in iOs

Tags: ios, core-animation

My parent CALayer is constantly moving with key frame animations. I need to add sublayers while it is moving. Is it possible? Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question: Create a `NSThread` that adds sublayers to the animated layer. Then call `[CATransaction flush]`.